# How much set theory is necessary for serious logic?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, advice

I'm currently studying logic at my university and I have been trying to squeeze in as much set theory on the side as possible. Considering that I am spending quite a lot of time studying set theory independently from my logic coursework I have begun to wonder if it would be a better to devote my extra time to just the logic. Should I expect to encounter necessary set theory for logic in the logic texts that I will use as I advance or is it necessary to study set theory as well as logic to develop a firm grasp of logic?

Comment: For most branches of Logic, no more (and usually less) than one needs for analysis.

Comment: Which aspect of logic are you studying ? model theory ?

Comment: I'd say that it's *at least* necessary some grasp of ordinal and cardinal arithmetic. Other than that, it depends on your interests; this link may be of help: http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Answer (score 1):

There's logic and logic! And when does it start counting as "serious"?

For a first math logic course on first-order logic (and I'm including here things like the completeness proof for "ordinary", i.e. countable, languages) you need no serious set theory.

To be sure, it is entirely  standard to use set theoretic notation and say e.g. that a model has a domain which is a *set* equipped with functions and relations where those are also identified with sets of tuples from the domain. But actually, this set-theoretic talk is doing little real work at the outset (and even can be positively misleading). For example, instead of saying that -- in a certain case -- the domain of quantification is the set (singular) of numbers, we can instead say simply that the quantifiers run over the numbers (plural), and so on.

But once you get into e.g. the elements of model theory (compactness, upward and downward L-S theorems and their applications, and a little more), then you'll need to know something about ordinals and cardinals and something about the axiom of choice: so this is where you'll begin to need to know a little set theory.

But how much? Not a lot at the outset. Take a look at the Teach Yourself Logic Guide you can download from http:// logicmatters.net/tyl. Just one of the elementary books mentioned at the beginning of the section on Beginning Set Theory will give you more than enough to get into the other parts of a first course in mathematical logic  [Of course, as Asaf says in his comments, as you get further into serious model theory you get more and more embroiled with serious set theory!]

Comment: "Not a lot" may vary. For some model theory you need very basic set theory knowledge; for other model theory you need to understand large cardinals, and forcing arguments. Similarly with logic, if you switch to infinitary logic, or other stronger logics you may run into independence, forcing arguments, and large cardinals pretty fast (see the works of Magidor-Vaananen, or Bagaria's work on polymodal provability logics, to see the flavor of arguments that may come in).

Comment: Yes to Asaf! I was making a guess that the OP's rather unspecific "currently studying logic" (and evidently not doing a set theory course) indicated someone near the beginning ...

Comment: I like that slogan! I agree with your assumption, but it is still worth knowing what might lie ahead.

Answer (score -3):

You could say that set theory ***is*** logic - u have ontological axioms (like *existence*, *pairing* etc.) guaranteeing the existence of certain objects and *comprehension* essentially identifying *formulas* and *sets*. So what is the difference between 
$$\{x|S(x)\}\text{ and }S(x)$$

or $\{x\in A|S(x)\}$ and $A(x) \land S(x)$?

The thing with set theory is the following: that what it axiomatizes - the idea of something "*belongs to*" or "*is part of*" something - and how it axiomatizes it appears to be very familiar and somehow natural to our intuition. This seems to suggest that *set theory is the appropriate base for all mathematics*.

But despite that natural feeling with set theory, that claim seems to lack any further justification. Indeed more and more people think that taking set theory in any case for granted as a base for certain theories (like quantum physics or quantum gravity) might be just not appropriate and unjustified and involving it anyway might be the reason for some severe difficulties we face with these theories.

This is one motivation for being interested also in more general concepts like topos theory or typed $\lambda$-calculus - interestingly also theoretical physicists (f.i. C. Isham).

..for more views beyond *set theory* and *logic*(= introductory lectures on formal languages and systems, grammars, (in-)completeness + correctness, compactnes, Herbrand, Löwenheim-Skolem, computability, model theory, etc. ?) on *logic* u could f.i. see

[Barnes + Mack: An algebraic introduction to mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1475744919)

[C. Isham: `What is a Thing?': Topos Theory in the Foundations of Physics](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0417)

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: "This seems to suggest that set theory is the appropriate base for all mathematics." - no, that's not the reason set theory is an appropriate foundation.

Comment: I tried to point out that it seems not useful to distinguish between *logic* and *set theory* or *logic* and *model theory* or.. (actually what should *logic* mean then in such claims?). And I tried to introduce also other views that can also mean *logic* such as more algebraic views on *logic*.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila - ..what is the reason set theory is an appropriate foundation?

Comment: The reason is that set theory internalizes logic in a way which allows semantics as well. This allows us to talk about objects as if they exist (compare that to using second-order arithmetic as foundation, or even weaker systems, which sometimes can talk about provability, but can't quite construct all the objects). This allows us to take second-order statements like "There is a unique order complete field" and turn them into first-order statements in $\sf ZFC$ (or whatever set theory you prefer). And first-order logic is better than second-order logic, since it has reasonable proof theory.

Comment: Great answer - thanks! ..but what do u mean by *set theory internalizes logic in a way which allows semantics as well*? Say **ZF** - one might see it as just some axiomatic system based on a language including $\epsilon$ relation symbol. You mean the way **ZF** actually specifies $\epsilon$ is special because ..it allows semantics (but semantics you always have for formal languages and theories?) - you mean some kind of *internal semantics* - like the internal logic of a topos?
Could you refer some papers or literature about that point?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to compare this to topos theory, since I know virtually nothing about it (except that it supposedly exist, and it's not just an elaborate conspiracy against me). By internalizing I mean that in $\sf ZF$ we can define what is a logic, what are inference rules etc. etc. and construct all these systems as sets; and moreover these will usually be faithful to the meta-theory and its underlying logic, so we can now do all our mathematics as statements about sets, and all mathematical objects can be viewed as sets (including proofs, and so on).

Comment: A topos also internalizes logic (generally and naturally intuitionistic logic) as well as mathematical constructions analogue to intersections, unions, power sets, exponentioals etc. enabling to talk about all that not only in *external* (from the point of view of that topos) meta language but within the *interlnal language* of that topos. It seems right to say that this is the necessary point for saying a theory can be seen as a base for mathematics: internalization of what u need for mathematics - being mathematical objects and a way to discuss them / logic.

Comment: When we say that something can serve as a foundation for mathematics, we really want to say that by using that something we can prove the consistency of what we know, and apply the usual proofs that we are familiar with. This seems to me as a criteria which is reasonable, and it means that you really have to internalize *some* system which can talk about proofs and so on. Set theory does more, it internalizes "existence" as well. So while $\sf PA$ can talk about the fact that some theories prove this and that, $\sf ZF$ can talk about completeness and semantics (and thus, existence) as well.

Comment: I always thought these ontological axioms in ZF are somehow very special, if u think of other theories - f.i. topological axioms do not claim the existence of a topological space, or the group axioms not claim the existence of some group but they do not care about if such things might exist. They just offer an abstract description and if u have some structure u think it might be a group or space or whatever u should check the axioms to know its a model.

Comment: Axioms describe properties. They do not claim that there is a model of anything. That's the difference between syntax and semantics. Set theory allows us to translate syntax to semantics, and it allows us to turn high-order statements (which specify unique structures, for example) into first-order statements in set theory that way. But "group theory" is a list of axioms, not a class of models. The point I'm trying to make is that "structure" requires an underlying notion of set (or a whole other definition which is semantical), but axioms and proof can do without it, since these are syntactic.

Comment: I don't mean an axiom would explicitely claim the existence of a structure but the set theory axioms are somehow different as they claim existence of some set and pair sets and so on. The axioms of lets say topology do just describe properties of a topological space but not the existence of some space and exitence of lets say product spaces and quotient spaces etc. This *internalization of existence* of **ZF** seems to be the reason that **ZF** is enabled to (*internally*) talk also about *semantics*.